# Filtering events onclick with FullCalendar and the removeEvents method

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar to display my events from a JSON feed. It's working fine with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Initialize calendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    buttonText: {
        prev: 'Previous month',
        next: 'Next month'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'dddd'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: "events.json",
    disableDragging: true,                      
});
```

I'm trying to create a link that'll filter the events (ideally, it would be a select menu) using the removeEvents method. When I use the method and pass in an ID, the event gets removed. The documentation states:

> idOrFilter may also be a filter function that accepts one Event Object argument and returns true if it should be removed.

I read that the filter function should operate just like jQuery's grep method, but I don't understand how to implement it. I started writing the below, but I'm uncertain how to continue. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

```
...

$('#filter').click(function() {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar ( 'removeEvents', filter(events) );
}

...

function filter (events) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a `select` to accomplish this, you'll need some way of associating the `option`s in the `select` and the events in the calendar.  I've made the `option`s have ids that match those of the events in the calendar:

JavaScript (using the `events` property of fullCalendar):

```
events: [
    {
        id: 'event-1',
        title: 'Christmas Eve',
        start: '2010-12-24',
        allDay: true
    },
    {
        id: 'event-2',
        title: 'Christmas Day',
        start: '2010-12-25',
        allDay: true
    },
    {
        id: 'event-3',
        title: 'Boxing Day',
        start: '2010-12-26',
        allDay: true
    }
]
```

Your source of events does not have to be an array, this is just for the example I created.

HTML:

```
<select id="filter">
    <option id="event-1">Christmas Eve</option>
    <option id="event-2">Christmas Day</option>        
    <option id="event-3">Boxing Day</option>        
</select>
```

Now, the `removeEvent` function, as you described, takes one event object and returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the event should be removed:

```
function filter(event) {
    return $("#filter > option:selected").attr("id") === event.id;
}
```

What the `filter` function does is return true if the option selected under the select with id `filter` has an id that matches the id of the event that is passed to it.  This function can really be anything, as long as it returns true or false.

The way it works under the hood is that when you call `removeEvent` and pass your function, each of the events living on the calendar gets passed to that function and if true is returned, the event is removed.

I've made a working example (http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/QMyFu/) that also includes another example of a filter function and select element.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew, your filter function worked perfectly. Thanks! When I put my events in as an array in my javascript, the events will filter and I can move back and forth between months while keeping the filter intact. 

However, when I try to specify a URL to a JSON feed, the filter works fine, but if I go to another month and then return, all of the events get reloaded. 

Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I have another related question: how can I only filter the event selected? Right now, if I filter Christmas and then Boxing, the Boxing filter adds to the existing filter. I'm trying to get it to only filter by one event at a time. I tried adding to rerenderevents during the select menu change (in addition to calling the removeevents), but no luck. Thanks!

Comment: @Manoj: After some research I unfortunately can't quite figure out either of those issues.  The `rerenderEvents` function doesn't look like it's working, and I don't have a JSON feed handy to test your other issue...